# Unity sign in anynomous on android

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am trying to sign in anynomous on my android device in a game I have developed. When I run the game in the Unity Editor on my Macbook, everything runs smoothly and the database is update.

But when I compile and run it on my Samsung device, nothing happens, it just freezes. Does anyone have a clue why? I tried adding the sha1 key to the fingeprints of my project on Firebase, but no luck.

Here is the code:

```
private void anonymousSignIn()
{
    auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth
        .DefaultInstance;
    auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        user = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
            user.DisplayName, user.UserId);
        print("User signed in");
        removeUser();
    });
    print("Auth done");
}

private void prepareDatabase()
{
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance
        .SetEditorDatabaseUrl("mydatabaseadress/");
    DatabaseReference reference =
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    string userId = "Erik";
    User user = new User(userId, 24);
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);
    reference.Child("highscore").Child(userId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd need a stack trace at the point of the freeze or the Android logcat output to see what exactly is happening *I'd recommend [this Unity plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@0.1/manual/index.html) to help with parsing LogCat). Without knowing how all of this hooks together, it's hard to tell what "freeze" may mean in the context of your game or which call may be causing your problem. I do see a few possible issues:

1) `SetEditorDatabaseUrl` is not necessary, and I never use it in my own projects. I assume that `"mydatabaseadress/"` is a temporary value for this stack overflow question, but it's also an unnecessary potential bug surface if you only have one database in your project.

2) `removeUser` may be doing some work in Unity. For that reason, you should replace `ContinueWith` with `ContinueWithOnMainThread` (see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension)). That will also make sure that you get all of the necessary logging.

3) `auth.CurrentUser` will persist between runs of your game. Each call to `auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync` will create a *new user* - even if one's already been registered. You should change your auth code to something like:

```
auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
if (auth.CurrentUser == null) {
    auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
```

And remember to do any important work (such as calling `removeUser()`) in an `else`.

4) In your `prepareDatabase` call, you have a hardcoded `string userId = "Erik"`. If you have a database rule like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "highscore": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then it will always be rejected.

5) Similarly, if you're not waiting for `auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync` to complete before calling `prepareDatabase`, the default `"auth != null"` may automatically fail.

I hope that helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Thanks for the tips, indeed it is hard to know what is going wrong when you cannot debug. I will check the plugin.